# How to avoid the usage of element array for inner class?

Tags: java

In this code:

```
  @Override
  public boolean updateEntity() {
    final boolean[] success = {false};
    final PersistentEntityStore entityStore = manager.getPersistentEntityStore();
    entityStore.executeInTransaction(
          new StoreTransactionalExecutable() {
            @Override
            public void execute(@NotNull final StoreTransaction txn) {
              doUpdateThrowsException();
              success[0] = true;
            }
          });
    return success[0];
  }
```

What is the best approach so usage for `boolean` array can be avoided?

Comment: @maio290 You can't set the value of a local variable from within an anonymous class.

Comment: @marstran impossible.

Comment: Generally speaking the reason for this error is that you're passing a callback - so there is no guarantee that the code is executed immediately. It might well be the case that it return success but the code happens asynchronously and later fails. In this particular case, it's not a problem, but it's a very bad to get into in the general case.

Comment: The best way to fix this is to fix the API - for example take a `Callable<T>` as thr arguement to and return a `Future<T>` from `executeInTransaction`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use mutable object as status holder. `AtomicBoolean` should fit you.

Obviously "the best" approach would be to have ability to use return value `executeInTransaction` but since you have no influence on that part....

I also hope that you are 100% `executeInTransaction` is a blocking operation - this code won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a concurrency issue (and you do not know when the code will be executed), you should probably use a `CompletionStage<Boolean>` or some other kind of Future/Promise. That way you can differentiate if the thing failed or did not even run yet (your array or an `AtomicBoolean` will be false in either case, and you'd need a second one to decide if your transaction has already started).

If this code is synchronous, it seems there should be a more direct way to check if that exception you are trying to detect has been thrown. Doesn't this `executeInTransaction` have any way to return data or at least failures?

Comment: The `StoreTransactionalExecutable` is a class from a JetBrains' library thus I have no control over it, the way it works it that it throws an exception if error occurred during the transaction, thus setting the success down the line means transaction succeeded. 

And yes, the flow is blocking.

Comment: If it throws an exception, why do you still need the flag? Cannot the caller figure that out depending on whether it got an exception or not?